# include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR'

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Estoy realizando un proyecto en laravel 5.6 y al ejecutar el comando `php artisan serve` me sale el siguiente error en el navegador:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\AppESO-master\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

Pense en primera instancia que era un archivo que faltaba en mi xampp así que desinstale y reinstale todo nuevamente y nada. Cree un nuevo proyecto de laravel para descartar que mi problema solo ocurriese en ese proyecto, pero efectivamente al parecer cuando ejecuto el comando `php artisan serve` siempre me da ese error, visto desde la terminal seria este:

```
$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Tue May  7 07:16:09 2019] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such
 file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Tue May  7 07:16:09 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'C
:\xampp\htdocs\AppESO-master\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in U
nknown on line 0
```

Comment: Juan llevas un tiempo para saber que es mejor incluir el texto de tu error que dos imágenes, primero porque se leen mejor, son más accesibles, y segundo porque las imágenes podrían en un futuro no aparecer, lo que haría la pregunta inservible en un futuro.

Comment: No lo sabia David, pensé se vería de manera más clara y por eso lo coloque de esa forma, de todas maneras ya ha sido corregido, gracias por tu colaboración

Comment: Y la solución cual fue?, podrías compartirla?